# What's the meaning of "what a shock that must have been to her"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> If so, what a shock that must have been to her.

- "What a/an X" is an exclamation.
- "must" refers to a necessity.

But what's the meaning of the sentence(like sentence above) that combines them together?

The fuller text is here:

> Beverly has changed her seat so that she is no longer sitting beside
>   her husband and so that she doesn’t have to see Dana’s shape beneath
>   the sheet. So this is what has become of their weekend away, for which
>   she’d had such hopes. Her marriage facing imminent ruin. Stuck in an
>   isolated hotel in the thrall of a deadly ice storm, without power,
>   sharing the lobby with the corpse of a woman who may have been pushed
>   down the stairs by her wealthy fiancé. **If so, what a shock that must
>   have been to her.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Must", like most modals, has two different meanings: a *deontic* one about necessity or consequence, and an *epistemic* one about our knowledge (usually the speaker's knowledge).

In this context, *must* is epistemic, and *that must have been* means something like *I conclude that that was*. So the whole sentence means something like "I think that was a great shock for her".

Comment: Perhaps from the learner's point of view it might help to paraphrase as *I **am obliged to** conclude that [it was / would have been a shock],* since the word ***must*** in this context does indeed carry its normal significance of ***have to, be obliged to***. And I think in the general exclamatory construction *What a shock it was, What a day I've had, What fun we're having*, it might help to note that initial "intensifier" ***What*** can (almost?) always be deleted, and the remaining text resequenced with an *explicit* intensifier to give the intended sense of the exclamation...

Comment: *It was an **extreme** shock, I've had an **extreme** day, We're having **extreme** fun*.